# Codeigniter Email Libraries - Undefined property: stdClass::$email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i have tested to use email library from Code Igniter in the past and succed. But now, when i test it again i got this following error

```
Message: Undefined property: Gate::$email
```

Where Gate is the parent class.

This is how i configure the email library in my function

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from('no-reply@xxxx.com', 'xxxx.com');
$this->email->to($mail);
```

The error appear in the line of

```
 $this->email->from('no-reply@xxxx.com', 'xxxx.com');
```

From this code, i'm pretty sure it is configured properly.
If somebody have an idea about this error, please help me to fix this.

Comment: Can you post the code of your parent class gate??

Comment: sure i can post it @Saty